# Should I bother to return empty list if array of zero length exists?

Tags: java, collections

Taking this constructor as an example:

```
private final List<ArrayList<Integer>> adjList;
public Graph(int vertexCount) {
        adjList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(vertexCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
            adjList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }
    }
```

Here is someone wants a list of vertexes he would simply provide the vertex.

```
   public List<Integer> adj(int vertex) {
        return adjList.get(vertex); 
    }
```

Now if the vertex did not have any nodes connected to it, then the the return value would be list of size 0.
Is it of an advantage to return a an Collections.Empty_List by adding an explicit check like: if list size is 0  then return Collections.Empty_List ?

Comment: Arguably you could save a bit of memory that way, but there'd need to be a lot of zero size instances to make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do that, you already have the empty list instantiated.

What you can do, is use `return Collections.unmodifiableList(adjList.get(v))`, so that the user of your `Graph` cannot modify the internals

Answer (score 1):

You should return an [ImmutableList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) instead, I think that better expresses your intent (the returned collection is not supposed to be modified).

```
return ImmutableList.copyOf(adjList.get(vertex));
```

Perhaps you could change the return value of the method to `ImmutableList` so that clients can see that they should not even try to change it.
Provided that you can use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).